# Sub-directory problem when making in-memory file system for Flask web app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, data-structures, filesystems

I'm creating a virtual/in-memory file system as part of a Flask apps, where the user is creating files & folders and I'm saving them in a SQL DB and displaying the directory tree back to the user in the UI (think dropbox/google drive).

For reprex' sake, the relevant metadata in both the 'File' and 'Folder' SQL tables would be: `['object_id', 'parent_id', 'child_nodes']` where,

- object_id = the unique identifier
- parent_id = the parent object_id that a sub-file or sub-folder belongs to
- child_nodes = the child object_ids of a parent

I created Project and File classes to handle internal methods & properties (excluded but necessary). So ideally I need the classes in my end solution.

**The main problem I'm running into is appending sub-directories as `child_nodes` to directories.** This is observable [in the commented out code at the bottom] when iterating from `dir_list[1]` to `dir_list[2]`, where `dir_list[1]` would already have been appended to `dir_list[0]` and therefore wouldn't reflect the following iteration.

**Looking for any suggestion on how to implement this. I'm also entirely open to using different data structs altogether, so long as I can add metadata and format it the same way that `FileDir.create_tree()` does.** Note: I need to iterate through a theoretically infinite number of subdirectories, not just what is in my reprex.

```
# Objects for organizing each struct -----
class File():
    def __init__(self, file_list):
        self.id = file_list[0]
        self.name = file_list[1]
        self.parent = file_list[2]
        self.directory = False

class Directory:
    def __init__(self, dir_list):
        self.id = dir_list [0]
        self.name = dir_list [1]
        self.parent = dir_list [2]
        self.child_nodes = []
        self.directory = True

    def add_file_node(self, node):

        node = {
                'id': node.id,
                'name':  node.name,
                'parent': self.parent,
                'is_dir': node.directory
            }
        self.child_nodes.append(node)

    def add_dir_node(self, node):

        node = {
                'id': node.id,
                'name':  node.name,
                'parent': self.parent,
                'is_dir': node.directory,
                'children': self.child_nodes
            }
        self.child_nodes.append(node)


    def return_tree(self):
        tree = {
            'name': self.name,
            'children': self.child_nodes,
            'parent': self.parent,
            'is_directory': self.directory
        }
        return tree



class FileDir():
    def __init__(self, dir_list):
        self.dir_list = dir_list
    def create_tree(self):
        tree = []
        for directory in self.dir_list:
            tree.append(directory.return_tree())
        return tree

# Example Data (formatted as 2d-list from my SQL query) -----
dir_list = [
         ['10001', 'dir_1', None],
         ['10002', 'dir_2', '10001'],
         ['10003', 'dir_3', '10002'],
         ['10004', 'dir_4', None]
     ]

file_list = [
         ['21110', 'file1.csv', None],
         ['21111', 'file2.csv', '10001'],
         ['21112', 'file3.csv', '10002'],
         ['21113', 'file3.csv', '10003']
     ]

dir_objs = [Directory(d) for d in dir_list]
file_objs = [File(f) for f in file_list]

for fil in file_objs:
    if fil.parent:
        for i, x in enumerate(dir_objs):
            if fil.parent == x.id:
                x.add_file_node(fil)


# TODO Append sub_folders
# ...
# 
# for d in dir_objs:
#    if d.parent:
#        for i, x in enumerate(dir_objs):
#            if d.parent == x.id:
#                x.add_dir_node(d)
#                dir_objs.remove(d)

tree = FileDir(dir_objs)
tree.create_tree()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code accomplish your needs?

```py
# Objects for organizing each struct -----
class File:
    def __init__(self, file_list):
        self.id = file_list[0]
        self.name = file_list[1]
        self.parent = file_list[2]
        self.directory = False

class Directory:
    def __init__(self, dir_list):
        self.id = dir_list[0]
        self.name = dir_list[1]
        self.parent = dir_list[2]
        self.child_nodes = []
        self.directory = True

    def add_file_node(self, node):

        node = {
                'id': node.id,
                'name':  node.name,
                'parent': self.parent,
                'is_dir': node.directory
            }
        self.child_nodes.append(node)

    def add_dir_node(self, node):

        node = {
                'id': node.id,
                'name':  node.name,
                'parent': self.parent,
                'is_dir': node.directory,
                'children': self.child_nodes
            }
        self.child_nodes.append(node)


    def return_tree(self):
        tree = {
            'name': self.name,
            'children': self.child_nodes,
            'parent': self.parent,
            'is_directory': self.directory
        }
        return tree



class FileDir:
    def __init__(self, dir_list):
        self.dir_list = dir_list
    def create_tree(self):
        tree = []
        for directory in self.dir_list:
            tree.append(directory.return_tree())
        return tree

# Example Data (formatted as 2d-list from my SQL query) -----
dir_list = [
         ['10001', 'dir_1', None],
         ['10002', 'dir_2', '10001'],
         ['10003', 'dir_3', '10002'],
         ['10004', 'dir_4', None]
     ]

file_list = [
         ['21110', 'file1.csv', None],
         ['21111', 'file2.csv', '10001'],
         ['21112', 'file3.csv', '10002'],
         ['21113', 'file3.csv', '10003']
     ]

dir_objs = [Directory(d) for d in dir_list]
file_objs = [File(f) for f in file_list]

for fil in file_objs:
    if fil.parent:
        for i, x in enumerate(dir_objs):
            if fil.parent == x.id:
                x.add_file_node(fil)


for dir_obj in dir_objs:
   if dir_obj.parent:
       for potential_parent_dir_obj in dir_objs:
           if dir_obj.parent == potential_parent_dir_obj.id:
               potential_parent_dir_obj.add_dir_node(dir_obj)
dir_objs = [dir_obj for dir_obj in dir_objs if not dir_obj.parent]



tree = FileDir(dir_objs)
tree.create_tree()
```

This won't handle directory trees more than two levels deep, but your example data doesn't indicate that is necessary. Let me know if you do need to handle deeply nested hierarchies. You will need a different approach.

---

**EDIT**

Here is a more robust version that I developed with Python 3.8 that should handle arbitrary depth. I havn't tested it extensively, but hopefully this helps. No confusing recursion (on the surface).

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Union, List
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, field
import json


@dataclass
class Node:
    node_id: str
    name: str
    parent_node_id: str = None

    def to_tree(self):
        return asdict(self)


@dataclass
class File(Node):
    is_directory: bool = False


@dataclass
class Directory(Node):
    is_directory: bool = True
    children: List[Union[Directory, File]] = field(default_factory=list)

    def add_child(self, child: Union[Directory, File]):
        self.children.append(child)


class FileSystem:

    def __init__(self, *nodes):
        self.nodes = {node.node_id: node for node in nodes}
        for node in self.non_root_nodes:
            self.nodes[node.parent_node_id].add_child(node)

    def __getitem__(self, node_id):
        return self.nodes[node_id]

    @property
    def root_nodes(self):
        return [node for node in self.nodes.values() if node.parent_node_id is None]

    @property
    def non_root_nodes(self):
        return [node for node in self.nodes.values() if node.parent_node_id is not None]

    @property
    def directories(self):
        return [node for node in self.nodes.values() if node.is_directory] 

    @property
    def files(self):
        return [node for node in self.nodes.values() if not node.is_directory]

    def to_tree(self):
        return [node.to_tree() for node in self.root_nodes]



dir_list = [
    # id,      name,    parent_node_id
     ['10001', 'dir_1', None], 
     ['10002', 'dir_2', '10001'],
     ['10003', 'dir_3', '10002'],
     ['10004', 'dir_4', None]
 ]

file_list = [
     ['21110', 'file1.csv', None],
     ['21111', 'file2.csv', '10001'],
     ['21112', 'file3.csv', '10002'],
     ['21113', 'file3.csv', '10003']
]

dir_list = [Directory(*directory) for directory in dir_list]
file_list = [File(*file) for file in file_list]

file_system = FileSystem(*dir_list, *file_list)
tree = file_system.to_tree() 

print(json.dumps(tree, indent=2))
```

Comment: Yes, I do need it to go a theoretically infinite number of levels. Thanks for pointing that out though, I'll update the question. My gut tells me this could be done with a solid recursive algo, just not sure what the base case would be. But also unsure if that would be computationally efficient

Comment: No problem. - It is 3:15 AM here. I will update my answer tomorrow with a more robust solution that can handle arbitrarily deep hierarchies.

Comment: @mfnight Check out the revised code I posted above.

Comment: I'm also using v3.8 and had no problems. Benchmarks quite well on larger datasets too. Thanks!